# Update a Cell with C# and Sheets API v4

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Does anyone have a good C# example for updating a cell with the v4 API?

I have the get cell values c# example from the developer website working with Google Sheets API v4.  I am trying to modify the example to update a cell with a value of "Tom".  I'm stuck on the settings for `SpreadSheets.Values.Update`.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleSheetsAPI4_v1console
    {
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheet };
        static string ApplicationName = "TestSpreadsheet";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "<<myspreadsheetid>>";
            String range = "Sheet1!D5";  // single cell D5
            String myNewCellValue = "Tom";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(<<what goes here?>>, spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            Console.WriteLine(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Here is a working example using a console to write a singe cell.  Thank you everyone who assisted !!

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleSheetsAPI4_v1console
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets}; // static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "<MYSpreadsheet>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });



            String spreadsheetId2 = "<my spreadsheet ID>";
            String range2 = "<my page name>!F5";  // update cell F5 
            ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
            valueRange.MajorDimension = "COLUMNS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS

            var oblist = new List<object>() { "My Cell Text" };
            valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId2, range2);
            update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
            UpdateValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("done!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works well, but how does it translate to be part of a BatchUpdate? ie, if I wanted to update 2 (named) ranges in one request, how would I do that?

Comment: Hello @Slim,
This solution helped me but i want any solution which creates file on googleDrive
Can you please help me!

Comment: Thanks for this. I struggled setting up the access and service account, so wrote a blog post in case it helps someone: https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that finds this thread. I got the exception below:

> Exception Details: Google.GoogleApiException:
> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError 'valueInputOption' is required but
> not specified [400] Errors [ Message['valueInputOption' is required
> but not specified] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]]

Solved with:

```
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId2, range2);
update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
UpdateValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38841369/3850405

However this caused my data to get a single quote (') before the value I entered, like this:

[image]

After reading the documentation I saw that the examples used `"valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"`:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#write_to_multiple_ranges

After switching to `ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED` everything worked as expected.

```
updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
```

Answer (score 1):

The file "Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.cs" contains error: url "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}" not contains "?valueInputOption=RAW". Use this code temporarily:

```
String spreadsheetId = "rihhgfkjhgufhgHUGUJKGHUItgUIGUIgui";
String range = "Config!A2:E";
ValueRange valueRange=new ValueRange();
valueRange.Range = range;
valueRange.MajorDimension = "ROWS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS
var oblist=new List<object>(){12,3,4,5u,6};
valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> {oblist};

var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}?valueInputOption=RAW".Replace("{spreadsheetId}",spreadsheetId).Replace("{range}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(range));

JObject json = null;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + credential.Token.AccessToken);
    client.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    client.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "myprogram database updater google-api-dotnet-client/1.13.1.0 (gzip)");
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    var jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valueRange);
    var jsontemp = JObject.Parse(jsonstr);
    jsontemp.Remove("ETag");
    jsonstr = jsontemp.ToString();
    try
    {
        var res = client.UploadString(url, "PUT", jsonstr);
        json = JObject.Parse(res);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet
Ensure you comment out the following line of code.

```
credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");
```

Also this is what I used syntax wise and got it working.

```
String spreadsheetId2 = "<put yours here>";
String range2 = "<againyours>!F5";
ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
valueRange.MajorDimension = "COLUMNS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS

var oblist = new List<object>() { "ello" };
valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId2, range2);
update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
UpdateValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have access to read your sheet because I can see :

> static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };

Try to change "SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly" by "SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheet" or by "SheetsService.Scope.Drive". Maybe it's another syntax... If it's not a problem of authorization I can't help you, sorry... Good luck my friend.

Ps: On Xcode (objective-c) you must reset the simulator after modification of scope. For you (C#) I don't know.

Comment: You are correct would definitely not be read only.  I have changed to "SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheet".

Comment: I'm stuck on the syntax for Spreadsheets.Values.Update(<<what goes here?>>, spreadsheetId, range);

parameters 'spreadsheetId' and 'range' are strings, while the first paremeter is listed as needing to be a 'body'.

Answer (score 0):

First Create value range object like given below:

```
Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange requestBody = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange();
```