# Google Sheets API: golang BatchUpdateValuesRequest

Tags: go, google-sheets-api, google-api-go-client

I'm trying to follow the Google Sheets API quickstart here:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate

(scroll down to "Examples" then click "GO")

This is how I tried to update a spreadsheet:

```
package main

// BEFORE RUNNING:
// ---------------
// 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
//    and check the quota for your project at
//    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
// 2. Install and update the Go dependencies by running `go get -u` in     the
//    project directory.

import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"

        "golang.org/x/net/context"
        "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

func main() {
        ctx := context.Background()

        c, err := getClient(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        sheetsService, err := sheets.New(c)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
        spreadsheetId := "1diQ943LGMDNkbCRGG4VqgKZdzyanCtT--V8o7r6kCR0"
        var jsonPayloadVar []string
        monthVar := "Apr"
        thisCellVar := "A26"
        thisLinkVar := "http://test.url"
        jsonRackNumberVar := "\"RACKNUM01\""
        jsonPayloadVar = append(jsonPayloadVar, fmt.Sprintf("(\"range\":     \"%v!%v\", \"values\": [[\"%v,%v)\"]]),", monthVar, thisCellVar, thisLinkVar,     jsonRackNumberVar))

        rb := &sheets.BatchUpdateValuesRequest{"ValueInputOption":     "USER_ENTERED", "data": jsonPayloadVar}
        resp, err :=     sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(spreadsheetId,     rb).Context(ctx).Do()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)
}

func getClient(ctx context.Context) (*http.Client, error) {
        //     https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/go#step_3_set_up_the_sample
        //
        // Authorize using the following scopes:
        //     sheets.DriveScope
        //     sheets.DriveFileScope
             sheets.SpreadsheetsScope
        return nil, errors.New("not implemented")
}
```

Output:

hello.go:43: invalid field name "ValueInputOption" in struct initializer
hello.go:43: invalid field name "data" in struct initializer
hello.go:58: sheets.SpreadsheetsScope evaluated but not used

There are 2 things that aren't working:

1. It's not obvious how to enter the fields into variable rb
2. I need to use sheets.SpreadsheetsScope

Can anyone provide a working example that does a BatchUpdate?

References:
This article shows how to do an update that is not a BatchUpdate: [Golang google sheets API V4 - Write/Update example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691100/golang-google-sheets-api-v4-write-update-example)

Google's API reference - see the ValueInputOption section starting at line 1437: https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/sheets/v4/sheets-gen.go

This article shows how to do a BatchUpdate in Java: [Write data to Google Sheet using Google Sheet API V4 - Java Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107237/write-data-to-google-sheet-using-google-sheet-api-v4-java-sample-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following sample script? This is a simple sample script for updating sheet on Spreadsheet. So if you want to do various update, please modify it. The detail of parameters for spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate).

### Flow :

At first, in ordet to use the [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) in your question, please use [Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go). In my sample script, the script was made using the Quickstart.

The flow to use this sample script is as follows.

1. For [Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go), please do Step 1 and Step 2.
2. Please put `client_secret.json` to the same directory with my sample script.
3. Copy and paste my sample script, and create it as new script file.
4. Run the script.
5. When `Go to the following link in your browser then type the authorization code:` is shown on your terminal, please copy the URL and paste to your browser. And then, please authorize and get code.
6. Put the code to the terminal.
7. When `Done.` is displayed, it means that the update of spreadsheet is done.

### Request body :

For `Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate`, `BatchUpdateValuesRequest` is required as one of parameters. In this case, the range, values and so on that you want to update are included in `BatchUpdateValuesRequest`. The detail information of this `BatchUpdateValuesRequest` can be seen at [godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#BatchUpdateValuesRequest). When it sees `BatchUpdateValuesRequest`, `Data []*ValueRange` can be seen. Here, please be carefull that `Data` is `[]*ValueRange`. Also `ValueRange` can be seen at [godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#ValueRange). You can see `MajorDimension`, `Range` and `Values` in `ValueRange`.

When above infomation is reflected to the script, the script can be modified as follows.

### Sample script :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

// getClient uses a Context and Config to retrieve a Token
// then generate a Client. It returns the generated Client.
func getClient(ctx context.Context, config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
    cacheFile := "./go-quickstart.json"
    tok, err := tokenFromFile(cacheFile)
    if err != nil {
        tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
        saveToken(cacheFile, tok)
    }
    return config.Client(ctx, tok)
}

// getTokenFromWeb uses Config to request a Token.
// It returns the retrieved Token.
func getTokenFromWeb(config *oauth2.Config) *oauth2.Token {
    authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
        "authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

    var code string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&code); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code %v", err)
    }

    tok, err := config.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web %v", err)
    }
    return tok
}

// tokenFromFile retrieves a Token from a given file path.
// It returns the retrieved Token and any read error encountered.
func tokenFromFile(file string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    t := &oauth2.Token{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(t)
    defer f.Close()
    return t, err
}

func saveToken(file string, token *oauth2.Token) {
    fmt.Printf("Saving credential file to: %s\n", file)
    f, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to cache oauth token: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(token)
}

type body struct {
    Data struct {
        Range  string     `json:"range"`
        Values [][]string `json:"values"`
    } `json:"data"`
    ValueInputOption string `json:"valueInputOption"`
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(ctx, config)
    sheetsService, err := sheets.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets Client %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "### spreadsheet ID ###"
    rangeData := "sheet1!A1:B3"
    values := [][]interface{}{{"sample_A1", "sample_B1"}, {"sample_A2", "sample_B2"}, {"sample_A3", "sample_A3"}}
    rb := &sheets.BatchUpdateValuesRequest{
        ValueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    }
    rb.Data = append(rb.Data, &sheets.ValueRange{
        Range:  rangeData,
        Values: values,
    })
    _, err = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(spreadsheetId, rb).Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

#### Result :

[image]

### References :

- The detail infomation of `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate).
- The detail infomation of Go Quickstart is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go).
- The detail infomation of `BatchUpdateValuesRequest` is [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#BatchUpdateValuesRequest).
- The detail infomation of `ValueRange` is [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#ValueRange).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I accepted it. Can you tell me how you knew to setup the "body" struct? I did not find this in Google's documentation.

Comment: @Albert Braden Thank you. When I use Google APIs, I investigate the request body by seeing the scripts of library at GitHub. In your case, I saw [this](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#BatchUpdateValuesRequest) and [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/sheets/v4/sheets-gen.go#L1762). I hope this answer is useful for you.