# Unable to access Google Spreadsheets with a service account credentials using Golang

Tags: authentication, go, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am writing an AWS Lambda code for accessing and updating a spreadsheet with the URL as input using Golang. So far I am able to access the spreadsheet locally using OAuth Client ID by following the Google guide - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go

But as I want to run the code from AWS Lambda, I want to perform authentication using the Google Service account. I have created a service account and have received the credentials which contain the below information.

```
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "quickstart-1XXXXXXX806",
"private_key_id": "a1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3c3e5d8e",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMZ4C8......\nD\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "lambda@quickstart-1XXXXXXX806.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id": "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/lambda%40quickstart-1573627656806.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

}

I have read much documentation but I didn't find any references for accessing Google spreadsheets using a Google service account using Golang code. Every document refer to the following Github link - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client
But as I have recently started working in Golang, I really don't understand how to implement it. After reading the Google guide I understand the flow required for service account as below -
[image]

But I am not still able to write Golang code for this. I would appreciate if anyone could share some references:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@ZektorH answer helped me to complete this code. Below is the complete working example for pulling data from Google spreadsheets using Service Account.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/jwt"
    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)


func main() {

    // Create a JWT configurations object for the Google service account
    conf := &jwt.Config{
        Email:        "lambda@quickstart-XXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        PrivateKey:   []byte("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"),
        PrivateKeyID: "a1a6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe5d8e",
        TokenURL:     "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
        },
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)

    // Create a service object for Google sheets
    srv, err := sheets.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets client: %v", err)
    }

    // Change the Spreadsheet Id with yours    
    spreadsheetId := "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"

    // Define the Sheet Name and fields to select
    readRange := "Sheet1!A2:B"

    // Pull the data from the sheet
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    // Display pulled data
    if len(resp.Values) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No data found.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Name, Major:")
        for _, row := range resp.Values {
            fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[1])
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note that if you get an error as below:

> googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden

then probably you have not given permission to your google account to access that spreadsheet. If so-

- simply go in your browser to the Google sheet you want to interact with.
- Go to SHARE on the top right of your screen.
- Go to advanced settings and share it with email address of your service account ex. lambda@quickstart-XXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: Thank you for the tip on how to resolve the permission issue, this really made me crazy. Also, there is a better way to initialize the credentials as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691100/golang-google-sheets-api-v4-write-update-example/58797998#58797998

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I found some [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/GettingStarted.md#service-accounts) that explains how to use Service Accounts on Golang. There is an [example](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#ex-package--ServiceAccount) on how to perform authentication with Service Accounts on the documentation:

> ```
> // Your credentials should be obtained from the Google
> // Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).
> conf := &jwt.Config{
>     Email: "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
>     // The contents of your RSA private key or your PEM file
>     // that contains a private key.
>     // If you have a p12 file instead, you
>     // can use `openssl` to export the private key into a pem file.
>     //
>     //    $ openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -passin pass:notasecret -out key.pem -nodes
>     //
>     // The field only supports PEM containers with no passphrase.
>     // The openssl command will convert p12 keys to passphrase-less PEM containers.
>     PrivateKey: []byte("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----..."),
>     Scopes: []string{
>         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
>         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger",
>     },
>     TokenURL: google.JWTTokenURL,
>     // If you would like to impersonate a user, you can
>     // create a transport with a subject. The following GET
>     // request will be made on the behalf of user@example.com.
>     // Optional.
>     Subject: "user@example.com",
> }
> // Initiate an http.Client, the following GET request will be
> // authorized and authenticated on the behalf of user@example.com.
> client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
> client.Get("...")
> ```

Comment: Thanks @ZektorH for sharing the example and links. After changing the Scopes parameter, It worked for me. You really saved my life.