# How to update Google sheet CheckBox using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update one cell that has CheckBox data type. Is there any way to set CheckBox to state Checked trough the API? Can't find any c# example...

Comment: what if you simply set value to `True/False` or `0/1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Checking or unchecking checkboxes with the Google Sheets API is equivalent to updating the cell values to the booleans `true` and `false`.

- Use the method [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- Base your request on the featured example code for C#
- I am not an expert in C#, but the value range in your request body should look something like this:

```c
var list = new List<object>() { true };
requestBody.Values = new List<IList<object>> { list };
```

Reference for updating vlaues in C#:

- [Update a Cell with C# and Sheets API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462887/update-a-cell-with-c-sharp-and-sheets-api-v4)
- [In C# how do I go through a Google Sheets document and write into a specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927376/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-go-through-a-google-sheets-document-and-write-into-a-specifi)

Comment: My bad, didn't check send types by myself. Thanks for help it works.